# Menu not showed in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-appcompat, android-menu

I'm trying to display a mediaroute list in a menu but the menu doesn't show up and I don't understant why. The logcat doesn't show any error, so if someone see's why please give me an advice, thanks.

Code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat
import androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteActionProvider
import androidx.mediarouter.media.MediaControlIntent
import androidx.mediarouter.media.MediaRouteSelector
import android.R

class MenuCast : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mSelector: MediaRouteSelector? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_cast_activity)
        
        mSelector = MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
            .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK)
            .build()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.cast_options, menu)
        
        val mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item)
        val mediaRouteActionProvider =
            MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem) as MediaRouteActionProvider
        
        mSelector?.also(mediaRouteActionProvider::setRouteSelector)
        
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you customized the default theme? Do you have a Toolbar in your view layout, or are you using a theme that includes the window decor ActionBar?

Comment: Make sure the icon color is not the same as the toolbar background.